# Sort an Array of Dictionaries

Tags: iphone, ios, sorting

```
arrAll = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    if (isCategory && i==0) {
        secCount++;
        //            NSLog(@"cate %@",arrCategory);
        NSMutableArray *arrone = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
        for (int j=0; j<arrCategory.count; j++) {
            NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [[arrCategory objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"SuCategoriesString"],@"title",
                                  [[arrCategory objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"CategoryName"], @"subtitle",
                                  [[arrCategory objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"Favourite"] ,@"Favourite",
                                  [[arrCategory objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"Views"], @"Views",
                                  [[arrCategory objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"CommentCount"], @"CommentCount",
                                  [[arrCategory objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"Likes"],@"Likes",
                                  [[arrCategory objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"CatId"],@"CatId",
                                  nil];
            [arrone addObject:dict];
            [dict release];
        }
        NSDictionary *Dictmain = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"CATEGORIES",@"titHeader",
                                  arrone, @"arrayFill", nil];
        [arrAll addObject:Dictmain];
        [arrone release];
        [Dictmain release];
    }
    if (isTopic  && i==1)
    {
        secCount++;
        NSMutableArray *arrone = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
        for (int j=0; j<arrTopic.count; j++) {
            NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [[arrTopic objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"TopicName"],@"title",
                                  [[arrTopic objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"CategoryName"], @"subtitle",
                                  [[arrTopic objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"Favourite"] ,@"Favourite",
                                  [[arrTopic objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"Views"], @"Views",
                                  [[arrTopic objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"CommentCount"], @"CommentCount",
                                  [[arrTopic objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"Likes"],@"Likes",
                                  [[arrTopic objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"TopicId"],@"TopicId",
                                  [[arrTopic objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"SubCategoryName"],@"SubCategoryName",
                                  nil];
            [arrone addObject:dict];
            [dict release];
        }
        NSDictionary *Dictmain = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"TOPICS",@"titHeader",
                                  arrone,@"arrayFill", nil];
        [arrAll addObject:Dictmain];
        [arrone release];
        [Dictmain release];
    }
    if (isTip && i==2)
    {
        secCount++;
        NSMutableArray *arrone = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
        for (int j=0; j<arrTips.count; j++) {
            NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [[arrTips objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"TipName"],@"title",
                                  [[arrTips objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"TopicNameString"], @"subtitle",
                                  [[arrTips objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"Favourite"] ,@"Favourite",
                                  [[arrTips objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"Views"], @"Views",
                                  [[arrTips objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"CommentCount"], @"CommentCount",
                                  [[arrTips objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"Likes"],@"Likes",
                                  [[arrTips objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"TipId"],@"TipId",
                                  nil];
            [arrone addObject:dict];
            [dict release];
        }
        NSDictionary *Dictmain = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"TIPS",@"titHeader",
                                  arrone, @"arrayFill", nil];
        [arrAll addObject:Dictmain];
        [arrone release];
        [Dictmain release];
    }
}
[arrAll retain];
NSLog(@"Array before sorting:%@",arrAll);
```

I want arrAll to be sorted based in Views,CommentCount,Likes,Favourites and i want result same as this can any body help me with this its urgetnt.
         please sorry for formatting

Answer (score 0):

Here is a selection of possible array sorting functions from the [NSArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html):

```
– sortedArrayHint
– sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:
– sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:hint:
– sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
– sortedArrayUsingSelector:
– sortedArrayUsingComparator:
– sortedArrayWithOptions:usingComparator:
```

Answer (score 0):

this is simply an array sorting method. you have to use NSSortDescriptor

```
NSSortDescriptor *lastNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"CATALOG_NO" ascending:YES];
[nameArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:lastNameDescriptor]];
```

where initWithKey where you have to use your key value which value array you have to sort and name Array is your array which contain your array

Comment: This was doing sorting on aphanumaric basis and not on the type of key

Comment: Thanks for you kind effort and sorry for very late reply

Comment: it's sorting alphanumeric or alphabatically you just need to pass your  array object key

Answer (score 0):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortString  ascending:NO comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id firstObject, id secondObject)
            {
                return [((NSString *)firstObject) compare:((NSString *)secondObject) options:NSNumericSearch];
            }];

            arrContent = [arrContentOriginal sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];
```

Found This solution